# Возвращение уникальный значений из массива

Tags: javascript

Прошу обьясните.

1) Что это `Object.keys(obj)`

2) `obj[str] = true;` - а что мешает другому значению занаять его место.

```
function unique(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var str = arr[i];
        obj[str] = true; // запомнить строку в виде свойства объекта
    }
    return Object.keys(obj); // или собрать ключи перебором для IE<9
}
var strings = ["кришна", "кришна", "харе", "харе", "харе", "харе", "кришна", "кришна", "8-()"];
alert( unique(strings) ); // кришна, харе, 8-()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (или [с переводом](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff688127%28v=vs.94%29.aspx))
2. Тут без разницы какое будет значение, главное - это ключи объекта. Т.к. каждый ключ уникален, то все последующие, будут только перезаписывать значение существующего.

P.S. Кстати, вот вам еще один вариант реализации:

```
var arr = ["кришна", "кришна", "харе", "харе", 
  "харе", "харе", "кришна", "кришна", "8-()"];

function uniqueVal(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
console.log( arr.filter( uniqueVal) ); // ["кришна", "харе", "8-()"]
```

Comment: т.е. обьект (ключ : значение).
и ключь у обьекта всегда уникален и т.к.он уже записан то пвтор он просто проигнорит?

Comment: @msim, можно сказать, что проигнорирует, хотя если точнее, то всё же перезапишет значение у существующего ключа. В любом случае, ключ с таким же названием создан не будет (*на одном уровне вложенности, конечно же*).

Comment: не хочу убить твою веру в ум человека.Но вы даете созданному массиву с свойством filter функцию uniqueVal. но функции не даете никаких параметров

Comment: @msim, а оно ей надо? Обойдётся без параметров )) Если серьёзно, то окиньте взглядом этот метод [filter()][1]

   [1]:http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#filter

Comment: Для примера с кришной можно было бы и ссылку на первоисточник - авось пригодится вопрошающему.

Answer (score 1):

```
let beepbeep = [];
let imjeep = Array.from(new Set(beepbeep));
console.log(imjeep);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]