# Проверка элементов массива на уникальность

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть файл, который представляет собой базу данных программы учета. Моя задача - посчитать сумму всех заказов. Но тут вот проблема, в базе есть **повторяющиеся** строки, из-за этого сумма выходит на порядок выше.

> Задача: проверять время заказа и номер заказа, если совпадает - игнорировать.

Но вот никак не могу допереть как это сделать...

Вот, собственно, то что есть на данный момент:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var arr = [];
var newArr = [];
var dNewArr = [];
var sum = 0;
var dSum = 0;


xhr.open('GET', 'input.mfl', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status !== 200) {
    alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
}
var file = xhr.responseText;
var file = file.split('\n');

for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    arr = file[i].split('#')
    newArr.push(arr[4])
    sum += parseFloat(newArr[i]);
    dNewArr.push(arr[6])
    dSum += parseFloat(dNewArr[i]);
}

document.write('Без скидки: ' + sum + '<br>');
document.write('Со скидкой: ' + dSum + '<br>');
document.write('Скидка: ' + (sum - dSum));
```

Пример input.mfl:

```
742#?#Слава-Кассир#Слава-Кассир#15#0#15#2016@11@30@19@6@28#2016@11@30@19@6@28#False$Чернігівське світле розл. мал.#1
337#?#Слава-Кассир#Администратор#11132#20#8905.6#2016@11@30@16@1@58#2016@11@30@16@1@58#False$Салат из печени трески с гренками#4$Оливье с креветками и перепелиными яйцами#6$Сельдь под шубой#3$Мясная тарелка.#3$Рыбная тарелка.#3$Рыба фаршированная.#30$Холодец по-царски.#20$Блины с сёмгой и кремом из сыра "Буко"#5$Торт печёночный#3$Тарелка домашних солений.#3$Закуска из огурцов с укропом и чесноком.#3$Рулетики из баклажанов с мясом в томатном соусе.#3$Шампиньоны фаршированные моцареллой.#3$Свиные тефтели с черносливом.#3$Утка. запечённая с яблоками в медово-апельсиновой глазури.#42$Голубцы по-домашнему.#5$Хлеб#30$Каберне совіньйон червоне сухе#30$Одесса н/сол.#1$Козацька рада(Банкет)#20$Узвар#15$Картофель. запечённый ломтиками.#6
999#?#Слава-Кассир#Корбут О.#150#0#150#2016@11@30@18@9@55#2016@11@30@18@9@55#False$Американо#1$Молоко до кави#1$Чернігівське Біле розл. вел.#2$Чернігівське Біле розл. вел.#1$Чернігівське Біле розл. вел.#2
```

Работу можно посмотреть здесь:
https://dream-studio.org.ua/project/

Comment: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/352125/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0) посмотрите может поможет

Comment: что именно есть? что нужно сделать? что именно не работает?

Comment: @ProstoJohn, весь необходимый код, должен быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: @vov4ok Уже смотрел. Просто у меня все заходит одной строкой, я делю все это на массивы `var file = file.split('\n');` и в цикле перебираю все эти массивы, выделяю и суммирую значения. Не могу понять как исключать одинаковые массивы. Понимаю что это должно быть до цикла...

Comment: @Grundy Добавил код, не могу понять как реализовать перебор на уникальность.

Comment: добавь пример содержимого файла `input.mfl` чтобы было понято что ты грузишь и как разбираешь

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Comment: и какая часть в этих строках может совпадать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53548/discussion-between-prostojohn-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (2-ая строчка одинакова по дате и ID, её выпилит фильтр):

```js
let source = `742#?#Слава-Кассир#Слава-Кассир#15#0#15#2016@11@30@19@6@28#2016@11@30@19@6@28#False$Чернігівське світле розл. мал.#1
742#?#Слава-Кассир#Слава-Кассир#15#0#15#2016@11@30@19@6@28#2016@11@30@19@6@28#False$Чернігівське світле розл. мал.#1
337#?#Слава-Кассир#Администратор#11132#20#8905.6#2016@11@30@16@1@58#2016@11@30@16@1@58#False$Салат из печени трески с гренками#4$Оливье с креветками и перепелиными яйцами#6$Сельдь под шубой#3$Мясная тарелка.#3$Рыбная тарелка.#3$Рыба фаршированная.#30$Холодец по-царски.#20$Блины с сёмгой и кремом из сыра "Буко"#5$Торт печёночный#3$Тарелка домашних солений.#3$Закуска из огурцов с укропом и чесноком.#3$Рулетики из баклажанов с мясом в томатном соусе.#3$Шампиньоны фаршированные моцареллой.#3$Свиные тефтели с черносливом.#3$Утка. запечённая с яблоками в медово-апельсиновой глазури.#42$Голубцы по-домашнему.#5$Хлеб#30$Каберне совіньйон червоне сухе#30$Одесса н/сол.#1$Козацька рада(Банкет)#20$Узвар#15$Картофель. запечённый ломтиками.#6
999#?#Слава-Кассир#Корбут О.#150#0#150#2016@11@30@18@9@55#2016@11@30@18@9@55#False$Американо#1$Молоко до кави#1$Чернігівське Біле розл. вел.#2$Чернігівське Біле розл. вел.#1$Чернігівське Біле розл. вел.#2`;

// Хранилища уникальных ID и времени открытия
let idStore = new Set(),
    timeStore = new Set();

let filtered = source.split(`\n`).filter(str => {
  // Извлекаем данные из очередной строки
  let [id,,,,,,, time] = str.trim().split('#');
  
  // Если хранилище уже содержит это значение - сразу возвращаем false, что отфильтрует это значение
  if(idStore.has(id) && timeStore.has(time))
    return false;
  else
    // Иначе добавляем (чтобы дальше дублей не копить) и продолжаем
    idStore.add(id), timeStore.add(time);
  
  return true;
}).join(`\n`);

console.info(filtered);
```

Comment: наверное ты меня неправильно понял, нужно выпиливать только те, которые одинаковые и по времени и по ID сразу

Comment: Так?...........

Comment: Отлично работает, только вот оно возвращает целое значение, а мне нужно дробное...

Answer (score 0):

Разделите ваш цикл на три этапа:

1. Подготавливает объекты, парсит, ковертирует
2. Фильтрует
3. Формирует результат

Когда флоу будет рабочим отрефакторите

https://jsfiddle.net/ahde0srq/

```
var result = {
    firstTotal : 0,
    secondTotal: 0
  };

file.split('\n')
  .map(function(row){
    var cols = row.split('#');
    return {
      "id": cols[0],
      "first": parseFloat(cols[4]),
      "second": parseFloat(cols[6])
    }
  })
  .filter(function(row){
    return row.first > 100;
  })
  .forEach(function(row){
    result.firstTotal += row.first;
    result.secondTotal += row.second;
  });
```

Comment: А что в данном примере оно конкретно фильтрует и как? Просто filter и map еще не использовал, вот и не очень понятно :(